# ELK Stack: Elk files corrupted- Corruption Issue

Tags: windows-services, devops, elastic-stack, elk, corruption

my Elk files are corrupted after every time I restart my windows server and some time without restart my files are corrupted.
I am running elk as a service in my server.
Every time after I restart my server services not started and it through error "The system can not find the file specified"
and when I try to start my elk with command it shows me different errors like some modules not found this is for all elasticsearch, kibana, logstash.

I have tried all the method mention on internet like hard disk repairing using windows tools and reinstalling my complete elk stack every time after it get corrupted.
I have checked my hard disk health and it seems fine.

Please tell me guys what should I do ?
Thanks in advance.